# http.get(url) in flutter not accepting string value. It says string value cant be assigned to uri type

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter but few days ago http.get(url) where url as string was being accepted but now its not working.
It says string value cant be assigned to URI

```dart
Future getNews() async{
  var client = http.Client();
  var response = await client.get('http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-02-17&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=230538c0a3f2450ba9ddf5802220ccf9');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the documentation of Flutter [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#2-make-a-network-request) you can't give a string to the get method.

Like you said you need to use Uri.

```
return http.get(Uri.https('your_url'), headers_if_you_need);
```

You can also use Uri.parse like this

```
return http.get(Uri.parse('your_url'));
```

Comment: Also the second argument to `Uri.http(s)` is for a path, not for headers.

Comment: Yes my mistake I mixed with. the get method. (who takes  uri and headers)